# How to fix width of bar in plotly R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

Plotly is one of the most useful plotting packages in R, but I am facing a very basic issue with it.

When I am drawing a barplot , it looks ok in a small screen, but as soon as I resize the window , it covers the whole window, making it ugly.

As my requirement is dynamic , number of bars on the plot changes, but I want to keep the bar width look decent.

[image]

But when it gets resized

the code which I am using to plot the barplot is simple and I hope need not be explained . The width option doesnt make any impact on the graph.

Am I missing anything?

```
 ds <- as.data.frame(matrix(c('some_name',2300),nrow = 1,ncol=2))
colnames(ds) <- c('name','value')

plot_ly(ds,x=name,y=value,type='bar') %>% layout(width = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option called bar size in ploty, but you can use bargap option in the layout.

Comment: I'd suggest improving grammar and formatting to more "formalized" English (see [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280581/grammar-corrections-good-or-bad) discussion). Also, providing an example of code for the `bargap` option that you've mentioned (or something similar) that OP can directly use would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set the `autosize=F`. So correctly it should be :

`plot_ly(ds,x=name,y=value,type='bar') %>% layout(width = 100, autosize=F)`

Another option is to set width and height in the `plotlyOutput` (keeping the `autosize=T`):
`plotlyOutput("plot", height="700px", width="200px")))`

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the answer either, but I found an alternative solution, which is to use dot plot, instead of bar chart.

See: https://plot.ly/r/dot-plots/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the width of the bars, just use the `width` argument inside of `add_trace` or `add_bars`

```
ds <- data.frame(name = "some_name", value = 2300)
plot_ly(ds) |>
  add_trace(x=~name, y=~value, type = 'bar', width = .1)
```

If you are looking to change width of the plot itself, add `width` inside the `plot_ly` function

```
ds <- data.frame(name = "some_name", value = 2300)

plot_ly(ds, width = 200) |>
  add_bars(x=~name, y=~value, type = 'bar', width = .1)
```